# ChildViewController + ContentSize + Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is it possible to manage frame of `childViewController` in the same way like subviews? I mean, is `childViewController` can calculate frame based on content, like for example `UILabel` based on inserted text?

I use `intrinsicContentSize` to determine `contentSize` of custom `UIView`s.

I found `preferredContentSize` property but when I change its value then nothing happen.

#### Example

I have `FromViewController` which contains `UITableView`. The `UITableView` will contain about 2 - 3 cells and whole height of these cells will be smaller than screen height.

Now I want to add the `FromViewController` to another `ViewController` as `childViewContoller`. I will pin `FromViewController`'s view to `parentView` to leading, trailing and bottom.

My goal: I don't want to set height constraint for `FromViewController`. I want to `FromViewController` calculate height by itself.

Comment: You don't want to pin the top?

Comment: no, I want to make childViewController height based on content size height

Comment: i think you should try this. give height constraint to FromViewController and calculate its tableview contentSize than give its contentSize height to constraint. and load it to parent view controller.

Comment: yea, it should works but I looking for a solution similar to UIView`s intrinsicContentSize, my goal is to omit height constraint if it is possible

Comment: than have you tried tableview automated dimension class.? the last i know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 let objYourVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewcontroller") as! YourViewcontroller;
   configureChildViewController(childController: objYourVC, onView: self.view)


extension UIViewController {
     func removeChildViewController(controller : UIViewController){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            controller.view.alpha = 0
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft , animations: {
            }) { (finished) in
                 controller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
                 controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
                 controller.removeFromParentViewController()
            }
        }
    }
    func configureChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, onView: UIView?) {
        var holderView = self.view
        if let onView = onView {
            holderView = onView
        }
        childController.view.tag = 1;
        holderView?.addSubview(childController.view)
        addChildViewController(childController)
        constrainViewEqual(holderView: holderView!, view: childController.view)
        childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        childController.view.needsUpdateConstraints()
        childController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        childController.view.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            childController.view.alpha = 1
        }) { (finished) in
            childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
    }


    func constrainViewEqual(holderView: UIView, view: UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                                        toItem: holderView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: holderView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: holderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: holderView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        holderView.addConstraints([pinTop, pinBottom, pinLeft, pinRight])
    }
}
```